# Does Challah bread need to be braided?

Tags: bread

I need to bake Challah bread for sandwiches for a large number of people.  Can I avoid the braiding? is it important to the final taste?

Answer (score 16):

The most common form of Ashkenazi (Central and Eastern European) challah is braided.  However, other shapes are not unknown.

For the Jewish New Year, *Rosh Hashanah*, Ashkenazi Jews eat a round challah.  These are sometimes still braided, but often they are not.  To make a round (unbraided) challah, we follow the same exact recipe, but after bulk fermentation, instead of divding the dough into 3/6/8 strands and braiding them, we form a log, or tubular shape, like a French *batârd*, then twist this log into a short spiral.

And, of course, we must remember that Ashkenazis are not the only Jews in the world.  Sephardic and Mizrahi Jews do not typically make braided challah.  They make round challah all year: https://cooking.nytimes.com/recipes/1017858-sephardic-challah-with-whole-spices

---

Note: it's not "challah bread" - it's just "challah".  Just like we don't say "baguette bread" or "ciabatta bread" or "brioche bread" or "focaccia bread"

Comment: I know lots of people who say "brioche bread" and "foccacia bread", sadly.

Comment: @FuzzyChef, yes, I thought that pronouncement might have been too optimistic.  Still, not as bad as "chai tea" (tea tea).

Comment: Wait, it's not called "ciabatta bread"?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 Formally, no, it’s just ‘ciabatta’, just like spagetti isn’t called ‘spagetti pasta’. The practice of appending ‘bread’ to that (or any of the other examples in the answer) is an English thing, just like ‘chai tea’, ‘panko bread crumbs’, or any number of sauces (tzatziki and sririacha come to mind immediately as common examples that do not need ‘sauce’ appended but usually do have it in English, but there are a _lot_ of sauces that native Anglophones like to append ‘sauce’ to the proper name of).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn:  Maybe we Anglos should start calling it "ketchup sauce" or "mustard sauce" or "mayonnaise sauce" for the sake of fairness.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn - How do you feel about the phrase: "Pumpernickel Bread" as differentiation from pumpernickel dinner rolls or bagels?

Comment: @GregNickoloff Not exactly fond of it, but it’s established enough that there’s not much chance of convincing people it’s redundant.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn - Agree. I found brioche hotdog (and hamburger) buns at the grocery the other day... so I feel less "funny" about the phrase "brioche bread" now. Incidentally, they were tasty, but I didn't let people see me eating them. We must continue to stand strong against "queso cheese" though.

Comment: languages evolve, Prescriptivism is dumb.

Comment: And let's not get started on "tuna fish"...

Comment: @LaconicDroid I was just about to mention that! As a BrE speaker (we don't say it) it baffles me every time I hear it. Why for tuna, and not other fish? I don't get it. At least if it were consistent - salmon fish, bass fish, and so on... 'Naan bread' & 'pitta bread' are fairly common here though (equally proscribed - just somehow slightly more excusable if it's a loanword imported from wherever the food's from I think).

Comment: I bake ciabatta bread.  I bake focaccia bread.  I bake the loaves that remind me of the good times, I bake the loaves that remind me of the better times.

Comment: @Juhasz ‘Chai tea’ makes some sense, because in English ‘chai’ is is coming to mean ‘masala chai’ (i.e. black tea with a blend of aromatic spices), or even just the spice blend alone. Hence drinks such as ‘chai latte’ and ‘vanilla chai’ with little or no black tea in them. So ‘chai tea’ distinguishes it from those.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert In UK (and) AU English, it's called "tomato sauce", not "ketchup". ;)

Answer (score 8):

A challah recipe does not require braiding for its flavour or to bake properly – but it does usually require braiding in order to be called challah. Feel free to leave it out, but (if your audience are familiar with challah) you might get questions about why it isn't braided. You could also just call it 'enriched bread' which is a more general term.

Answer (score 4):

It's not important for the flavor, but it is important for the shape, and for making sure that the challah is done all the way through. First, if you just put a round mass of challah dough on a baking sheet it's going to tend to spread out rather than rising up, and you'll end up with a very flat, wide loaf (which might be OK, but might not). Second, as an enriched bread, challah tends to have a problem with being undercooked in the center.

So if you want one big loaf for slicing for sandwiches, I'd suggest putting it in some kind of loaf pan or cloche to make sure it keeps a round shape, and give it lots of time to finish cooking and check it with the tap test.

Alternately, you could make [challah rolls](https://milkandpop.com/challah-rolls/), which are just the same dough rolled into small balls.  The linked recipe makes small knots with them, but you don't have to do that; rolling them into balls and making small "slider bun" rolls works fine.

Comment: One traditional, simpler approach to shaping a challah is to make a ["section challah"](https://www.karenskitchenstories.com/2014/07/section-challah.html), where the dough is divided, but not braided, and then placed in a row in a loaf pan.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your advice and suggestions.  I made Challah rolls, which came out lovely and looking good.  I had to hand knead the dough (which I did for 15 minutes)  but the rolls were a bit too dense/thick. No good to be use as a sandwich roll. Any suggestions on how to make them more 'fluffy'

Comment: @HEBW5 post that as a new question, it's not going to get answered in comments.. There might also be an existing question with an answer that'll help you, so check for that first, of course.

Comment: What Kat said.  Post a new question, I'll look for it.

Answer (score 0):

I have made challah by rolling bits of dough into small balls and piling them up to form a loaf shape. This leads to a loaf with a similar level of irregularity as braided challah, but is easier to construct (e.g., when baking with small children). So far as I can tell, it tastes exactly the same as braided challah.

Answer (score 0):

The shape won't dramatically affect the flavor. I worked at a bakery many years ago where we made Challah braids for the weekend but for our day-to-day sandwich needs we made Pullman loaves for slicing with this interesting technique:

- Divide a loaf's weight of dough into 8 pieces
- Shape them into balls as though you were making rolls
- Tuck the balls into a buttered Pullman in a 4x2 grid
- Rise and bake as normal

The individual balls all merge into a single loaf with a pleasing bumpy top and an overall rectangular cross-section that is perfect for sandwiches.

If you don't have a Pullman, a regular loaf pan should do fine, but try 6 balls in a 3x2 arrangement.